# CSVHelper How to read two csv file and join them based on ID in C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to read two CSV files using CSVhelper in my C# program. Both files have the same ID, but one has missing information that needs to be patched and saved to the list.

For example:

project1.csv has the following info:

```
SN  ID   Name
1   245  Moon
2   123  Sun
3   121  Water
4   253  Fire
```

project2.csv has the following info:

```
ID Location
121 Japan
245 Finland
```

I want to update the project1.csv to include location info from project2.csv based on ID:

```
SN ID Name Location
1 245 Moon Finland
2 123 Sun
3 121 Water Japan
4 253 Fire
```

How can it be done using CSVHelper in C#?

Comment: Post your attempt to solve the problem along with specific questions.

Comment: read both files into 2 arrays of objects. then use LINQ join to create new array

Comment: After you read the files then you just need to left join 2 lists as @pm100 recommend

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Location` optional on the first object when you read it in.  Then when you read the second file, loop through the objects to update the records from the first file before saving them back.

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<Project1> project1;
    List<Project2> project2;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Project1.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        project1 = csv.GetRecords<Project1>().ToList();
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(@"C:\Project2.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        project2 = csv.GetRecords<Project2>().ToList();
    }
    
    foreach (var project in project2)
    {
        var record = project1.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == project.Id);
        
        if (record != null)
            record.Location = project.Location;
    }
    
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Project1.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(project1);
    }
}

public class Project1
{
    public int SN { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Optional]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class Project2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```